# Variable calculation time

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to calculate a string once (basicaly a concatenation) in a variable using the result of my report's query and then submit it to my subreports.

But for the moment it's calculated in this order (let say operation A is my variable calculation and operation B is my subreport's call) :

A B A B A B ...

And what I'm looking for is A A A ... B B B (here every Bs have in parameter the last calculation of A).

Is there a solution which solve my problem like this (I guess it's a calculation time problem) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the sample to better understand your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change when a variable is calculated, you can use the `resetType` and `incrementType` attributes.

If you want it to only be calculated once (at the beginning of the report), set `incrementType="Report"`. You will also have to change the `variableExpression` to an `initialValueExpression`.

Example:

```
<variable name="var1" class="java.lang.String" incrementType="Report">
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{foo}+$F{bar}]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Comment: It's partly what I'm looking for. I want my variable to be calculated once (at the begining of the report) but my variable's calculation must be done on the whole set of results returned by my report's data query.

Comment: That makes things a bit more difficult then. I'd suggest calculating it at the end of the report and using the evaluationTime attribute to delay the fields that rely on it, but I don't think that would work with subreports. Could you calculate it before running the report and pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: I can't, i'll try by using subdataset. I'll give you a feedback if it works.